# DC ground connected to protective earth with a fuse

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, grounding, wiring

I read a document about industrial wiring example.

I found this wiring example:

[image: Ground connected to Protective Earth with Fuse]

In this picture, we have a 24VDC power supply. The input of the power supply is 220VAC. At the bottom, the ground output from the power supply is wired to the same protective earth as the 220VAC input but with a fuse.

Is the symbol in the picture that I call a fuse really a fuse?

Why do we need to wire GND to protective earth with a fuse?

Comment: No, it's not a fuse. It's a jumper, when put on, the GND becomes at earth potential.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, thanks so much.
So, if that component is jumper. We have option to connect and disconnect it, right?

Do you know, why does someone give option to connect or disconnect a DC ground to a protective earth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not a fuse, it is a bonding terminal so you can either have a floating output or ground referenced output.